# For what values of $a$ does $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{x+1}dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus

The question is: for what values of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the integral $$I(a)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^a}{x+1}dx$$

converges?

By using Wolfram Alpha, I found out that:

If $a\le -1$, then $I(a)$ doesn't converge.

If $-1<a<0$, then $I(a)$ does converge.

If $a\ge 0$, then $I(a)$ doesn't converge.

As $\dfrac{x^a}{x+1}\ge 0$ for every $x\ge 0$, I want to use the comparison test, but I don't know what other function I could use.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should test various values of $\alpha$ you got from WolframAlpha. You have the answer staring at you in the face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $a\geq 0$ first. Then because $x+1\geq 1$ so we never worry about as $x$ close to $0$. Now let's look at what will happen as $x$ goes to $\infty$. So as $x\to\infty$, we have $x^a/(x+1)$ is approximately the order of $x^{a-1}$ and since $a-1\geq -1$ we never have integral converge as at blow up when you integral to infinite.

Now Let's look at case $a\leq -1$. We only need to prove that the integral will blow up in $(0,1)$. When $x\in(0,1)$, $x^a/(x+1)\geq \frac{1}{2} x^a$, and as $a\leq -1$, the integral will blow up again.

Finally, when $-1<a<0$, we divide the integration into two parts, i.e.,
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x+1}dx =  \int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{x+1}dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{x^a}{x+1}dx$$
The first part converge because $x+1\geq 1$ and $a>-1$. Now the second part, we have as $x$ is large enough, $x^a/(x+1)$ is approximately the order of $x^{a-1}$ and hence the integral converge as $a-1<-1$